# remove attribute class and id and style from posts wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want remove attribute class and id and style from posts wordpress

i see in all posts class and id and same of style attribute

`<h2 id="gydde" style="color:#fff" class="iyjf"><span id="tttu" class="jfrrg"><b class="gr5" id="krttn" style="color:#fff">text</b></span></h2>`

i want after save post clean code in posts saved in database like this

```
<h2><span><b>text</b></span></h2>
```

any way to do check and filter posts after publish and update and remove id and class

i see for php

```
    <?php
function stripUnwantedTagsAndAttrs($html_str){
  $xml = new DOMDocument();
//Suppress warnings: proper error handling is beyond scope of example
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
//List the tags you want to allow here, NOTE you MUST allow html and body otherwise entire string will be cleared
  $allowed_tags = array("html", "body", "b", "br", "em", "hr", "i", "li", "ol", "p", "s", "span", "table", "tr", "td", "u", "ul");
//List the attributes you want to allow here
  $allowed_attrs = array ("class", "id", "style");
  if (!strlen($html_str)){return false;}
  if ($xml->loadHTML($html_str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD)){
    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName("*") as $tag){
      if (!in_array($tag->tagName, $allowed_tags)){
        $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
      }else{
        foreach ($tag->attributes as $attr){
          if (!in_array($attr->nodeName, $allowed_attrs)){
            $tag->removeAttribute($attr->nodeName);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $xml->saveHTML();
}
?>
```

i dont know how to it for wordpress with remove attributes class id and style

Answer (score 0):

The PHP method you posted in the question can be implemented with WordPress filter:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/field_no_prefix_save_pre/

So the code should look something like:

```php
<?php

add_filter( 'content_save_pre' , 'my_sanitize_content' , 10, 1);

function my_sanitize_content( $content ) {
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    //Suppress warnings: proper error handling is beyond scope of example
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    //List the tags you want to allow here, NOTE you MUST allow html and body otherwise entire string will be cleared
    $allowed_tags = array("html", "body", "b", "br", "em", "hr", "i", "li", "ol", "p", "s", "span", "table", "tr", "td", "u", "ul");
    //List the attributes you want to allow here for example ["class", "id", "style"]
    $allowed_attrs = [];
    if (!strlen($html_str)){return false;}
    if ($xml->loadHTML($html_str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD)){
    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName("*") as $tag){
      if (!in_array($tag->tagName, $allowed_tags)){
        $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
      }else{
        foreach ($tag->attributes as $attr){
          if (!in_array($attr->nodeName, $allowed_attrs)){
            $tag->removeAttribute($attr->nodeName);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $xml->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: thank you for help but i need disable attr not allow it for class,id,style

Comment: If I understand your request, you would like to strip all the attributes from all the tags. To achieve so, you can use the code above, just modify `$allowed_attrs` to be empty array, `$allowed_attrs = [];`

Comment: after update post nothing retrun only empty code

Comment: i see the code can do what i need but i want when save or update post

add_filter('the_content', function( $content ){
    //--Remove all inline styles--
    $content = preg_replace('/ id=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/','',$content);
    $content = preg_replace('/ class=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/','',$content);
    $content = preg_replace('/ style=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/','',$content);
    return $content;
}, 20);

Comment: this last code i try find here i try it but got error 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92186/119976

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to avoid quotes and encodes problems:

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'sanitize_attrs_content', 10, 1);
function sanitize_attrs_content($content)
{
    if (empty($content)) {
        return false;
    }

    $tags = array('b', 'br', 'em', 'hr', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 's', 'span', 'table', 'tr', 'td', 'u', 'ul', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'cite', 'blockquote');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $content = preg_replace('/<' . $tag . '\b[^>]*>/i', '<' . $tag . '>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/<\/' . $tag . '>/i', '</' . $tag . '>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/<' . $tag . '\b[^>]*>/i', '<' . $tag . '>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/(<' . $tag . '\b[^>]*)(id|class|style)="[^"]*"/i', '$1', $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```